# How to print the content of variables inside math expression using Latex and Sympy in Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt, latex, sympy

I am working on a software that solve an engineering problem. The software should printout the calculation for the user in a pretty mathematical expression format. I used Matplotlib,Latex and Sympy in PyQt and succeeded to do everything I wanted except for displaying the values of the variables in the form of a fracture (please see the picture below to understand what I mean). Also, I would like to know how to control the font size and style of the latex text(see the picture). below is a part of the code.

See this picture

[image]

```
def Calculate(self):
    plt.rc('mathtext', fontset='cm')

    self.right_column_stiffness = int(self.lineEdit_3.text())
    self.left_column_stiffness = int(self.lineEdit_4.text())
    self.beam_load = int(self.lineEdit_4.text())

    w=self.beam_load*(1000/12)
    g=386.1
    self.mass = w/g

    formula=r'm=\frac{w}{g}='

    self.result_figure.text(.05, .85, r'${}$'.format(formula+latex(w)), fontsize=20)
    [enter image description here][1]        
    self.result_canvas.draw()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions you have asked:

1. The font size of latex representation of fractions can be changed in two ways. First is to surround the fraction latex code with `\displaystyle` block.

   ```
   formula = r'm={\displaystyle\frac{w}{g}}'
   ```

   Other option is to change `'${}$'` to `\[{}\]` in the following line.

   ```
   self.result_figure.text(.05, .85, r'\[{}\]'.format(formula+latex(w)), fontsize=20)
   ```
2. In order to print the values contained in variables as a fraction rather than the final answer, you will have to manually construct another latex text.

   ```
   value = r'${{\displaystyle\frac{{{0}}}{{{1}}}}}$'.format(w,g)
   ```

Here is my example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import rc   # Added these two lines
rc('text', usetex=True)

formula = r'm=\frac{{w}}{{g}} = \frac{{{0}}}{{{1}}}'.format(100,20)

plt.plot( [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3], '.')
plt.text(1,1,r'\[{}\]'.format(formula),fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

Which gives the following result[image: result]

Comment: Thank you for your respond @Amit Singh. But none of that worked! I tried everything you suggested but nothing work. please see the picture. https://ibb.co/f9qzAz

Comment: I had tried these in Matplotlib before posting and they all seemed to work.

Comment: Thank you very much and I believe you.  I tried your exact code and this is what I got(please see the picture) https://ibb.co/ngB3Ne . It might be a problem on my computer (latex or I should import something different). please help

Comment: It seems your `matplotlib` is not setup to render LaTeX. I have added 2 lines in my example code. Can you try that?

Comment: I tried it and the result was an error -- see the picture please: https://ibb.co/dwRsYK

Comment: You may have to create another question about LaTeX not working in your Matplotlib set up first. This problem in unrelated to your question in this post. It will be better if you can post the full error message texts that you get rather than screenshots.